# Is it ok to only write down formulas in the detailed description but not in the figures?

Tags: uspto, writing, formula

I wonder whether it is ok to only write down formulas in the detailed description but not in the figures. On one side, I see patents that only write down formulas in the detailed description but not in the figures ([example](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/61/53/35/28367e409694a9/US20220245179A1.pdf)), but I've recently been told formulas themselves aren't patentable and therefore should be written down in the figures to show how they are part of the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“I've recently been told formulas themselves aren't patentable and therefore should be written down in the figures to show how they are part of the system.”

This is a possibility garbled version of the fact that a disembodied formula is not patentable but an application of a formula might be. The [famous case](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/450/175/) involves an automated method for controlling the curing of rubber. The formula is not new but the method as a whole is patented. This patent is an edge case and has been seen by some to be in contradiction to other famous cases.

What that has to do with putting a formula in a drawing is a mystery and not likely valid. The drawings and specification are both part of the disclosure and in which media of the disclosure information exists is not relevant.

Although often seen, a large amount of text in a drawing is frowned upon because text and drawings are separate things traditionally in patent documents. Specification get translated, drawings do not.